# Is GNU's nana library dead? Is there a successor in use?

Tags: c++, c, logging, assertions

Looking at http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/nana/ it seems that the last work was done on Nana four years ago, and the official gnu.org homepage for nana is a placeholder. Given how inactive projects tend to suffer from bitrot:

1. Has the project died?
2. Is there a successor?
3. Do folks have a different assertion/logging library for C/C++ that is superior?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a logging library, use Log4Cxx:
http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/

If you are looking for assertion checking, use a unit-testing framework such as UnitTest++:
http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/UnitTest++.html

Answer (score 1):

[Boost Test Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) is an option for the assertion checking part.